# Check if file is image or pdf

Tags: php, laravel

I need to check if a file is a image or pdf in php/laravel.

This is what I have now:

```
return $file['content-type'] == 'image/*';
```

In addition to the 'image/*' I need to add 'application/pdf'

How could this be added?

### Update

To be clearer, is there a way to add more allowable types without having to do a OR-condition. I got the answer now with in_array!

Comment: Are you asking how to add an OR condition in php??

Comment: But beware, `$file['content-type']` can be faked

Comment: @RiggsFolly ooo how would you check it?

Comment: I'd personally stay away from any frameworks until I understand the basics of the language..

Comment: @Devon Thank you for your help and encouragement!

Comment: @Olof "how would you check it?". That's the point, you can't really. You get a value from the client when the file is uploaded. The client can set the value to whatever it wants. You could cross-check with the file extension...but then a file extension can be set to anything too, regardless of the actual content of the file. The only way to really tell is to try and read the file with some software/library which is intended to read PDF files, and see if it can read from it. Same for images. But that takes CPU and I/O time. Depends what you want to do with this value as to how much you care.

Comment: @ADyson kk get it! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like this approach it saves a bit of typing

```
return (in_array($file['content-type'], ['image/jpg', 'application/pdf']));
```

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for the edit, as with most PHP functions I forget the argument order :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use an OR statement, i.e.

```
return ($file['content-type'] == 'image/*' || $file['content-type'] == 'application/pdf');
```

This is assuming you still just want to return true/false. So the caller will know that the file was either a PDF or an image.

Or do you mean that the return statement must produce a value which distinguishes between the two types? It's not clear.

If it's the latter than you might want something more like

```
$type = null;
switch ($file['content-type']) {
  case "image/*":
    $type = "image";
    break;
  case "application/pdf":
    $type = "pdf";
    break;
}
return $type;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the content-type of the file using OR condition to add additional check condition.

```
return ($file['content-type'] == 'image/*' || $file['content-type'] == 'application/pdf')
```

But it would be better if you put all conditional values in array and check existence of them using `in_array`.

```
return (in_array(['image/jpg', 'application/pdf'], $file['content-type']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return $file['content-type'] == 'image/*' || return $file['content-type'] == 'application/pdf';
```

"||" meaning OR